# Want to able to select multiple values for a particular attribute in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently working on a eCommerce website.
I put up my first product which is a variable product. I want to ad multiple value for a particular attribute.
for eg.: I have an Attribute of size which has value S, M, L, XL, XXL .
Now I have a variable product that is a red shirt, now this product is only available in 2 sizes L & XL. Now I want to be able to only select these 2 sizes for this product because these sizes are only available for this product. Currently in woo commerce I am allowed to only select 1 value for this.
Is there a way I can select multiple values. Please help.

Comment: little clearance if you disable the other attribute values which are not available yet then what you say it will work for you? or you want to select both values which one currently available?

Comment: I want to select both values eg: red shirt size: xl, l. 
so that the customer knows that this color shirt has only these 2 sizes.
I have seen one coding, that I think can help me. But I don't know how to implement it  http://www.remicorson.com/woocommerce-list-products-by-attribute-with-multiple-values/